# Wordpress memory error

Tags: php, wordpress, memory, fatal-error

I just installed a plug in I had purchased named "Timely Pro". Its an interactive calender program that allows the administrator to post new events with a description and images. Whenever I go into the back end and try view all of the events I've created, it throws this error:

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 32 bytes) in /home/content/75/10928675/html/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1551

I changed my memory limit in both php.ini and wp-config to 512M

> php.ini: memory_limit = 512M
>   wp-config.php: define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '512M');

Changing this did nothing for the error. Does anyone know any other definitions somewhere that could be causing this error?

Comment: See http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4096582/allowed-memory-size-of-x-bytes-exhausted and [this](http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Increasing_memory_allocated_to_PHP).

Comment: 512m is the local value and 64M is the master value. Do I need to find a way to change the master value?

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things you could check/try:

1. Verify that you've restarted Apache.
2. Verify that you are editing the right php.ini file. I use MAMP and each version of PHP naturally has its own copy. I made this mistake once before.
3. Check your Apache config's memory limit (e.g., httpd.conf). This SO answer might be of help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14573923.