# Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 1134559232) (tried to allocate 32768 bytes) in X:\wamp\www\xxx

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, wampserver

I am using **WAMP server(32 bits)** on local host on my personal PC. I have a big (very big) multidimensional array which gets its information by reading a CSV file which contains long sentences(the CSV file contains 20,000 row of information). The problem is that I get the following error when it goes through some calculations:

> *Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 1134559232) (tried to allocate
>   32768 bytes) in x:\wamp\www\xxx*

I tried different solutions like increasing `upload_max_filesize`, `post_max_size` , `max_file_uploads` and `memory_limit` or set it to -1 in php.ini or at the beginning of my scripts also, no one works. Please help me, and please do not ask me to re-architect my codes or change the version of WAMP, due to some reasons it is not possible. Thank you very much. :)

Comment: Did you restart apache after changing the limit in php.ini?

Comment: Assuming you changed the `memory_limit` setting in php.ini and restarted the apache service, did you make sure to update the correct php.ini file? (There are two, one for HTTP service and one for the command-line interface.)

Comment: I checked phpinfo() and it shows that memory_limit is set to -1, so it seems I have updated the correct one. I restarted apache, still no change :(

Comment: See if anything in this thread helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4399138/upper-memory-limit-for-php-apache

Comment: but I'm also getting the same error we hosted in Hostgator shared server how can I access those files

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I could find the solution. I found that when the PHP collection garbage is getting full, there is no way to free it. `Unset` and `gc_collect_cycles()` also are not effective. The only way is to use **`Function`** over different section of codes. In my case, I had a big script in a for loop, so I copied all my codes in a function, and in my loop I call the function. Each time function quiets, memory gets free. You may test it by adding `memory_get_usage()` once in your function and once out of the function to see the difference.

Comment: could you please help me in my issue??

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34560732/phpmyadmin-import-error-of-memory?noredirect=1#comment56865264_34560732

Answer (score 2):

It's none of those settings, it is `memory_limit`, the max amount of memory that a PHP script can consume. However, be sure that your server has enough resources before arbitrarily increasing this setting.

Comment: Thanks. Increasing memory_limit or set it to -1 did not help to solve the problem,

Comment: Are you seeing _exactly_ the same error with the same numbers? If so then there is something wrong with your change. Create a script containing `phpinfo();` and see what it says for the `memory_limit` and location of your php.ini file. Also restart apache to pick up the change

Comment: I checked `phpinfo()` and it shows that `memory_limit` is set to -1 . And Im not seeing exactly the same numbers in errors. I restarted apache, still no change :(

Comment: What's your PHP version? See the note in the answer from @Sharanya-Dutta about needing this to be compiled in to PHP pre 5.2.1

Comment: Yes I saw that,  my PHP version is 5.4.16

Comment: See the article @faintsignal refers to above. You may be hitting 32 bit memory limits, which is going to be hard to fix if you can't change the code or the server

Comment: Thanks  robjingram , my system is 64-bits, but I have to use the 32-bit version because the function for stemming can be installed as extension only on 32-bits one.

Answer (score 1):

Put this line at the beginning of your code:

```
ini_set("memory_limit", -1);
```

The PHP manual gives the following description of `memory_limit`:

> This sets the maximum amount of memory in bytes that a script is allowed to allocate. This helps prevent poorly written scripts for eating up all available memory on a server. Note that to have no memory limit, set this directive to -1.
>
> Prior to PHP 5.2.1, in order to use this directive it had to be enabled at compile time by using --enable-memory-limit in the configure line. This compile-time flag was also required to define the functions [memory_get_usage()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.memory-get-usage.php) and [memory_get_peak_usage()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.memory-get-peak-usage.php) prior to 5.2.1.
>
> When an [integer](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php) is used, the value is measured in bytes. Shorthand notation, as described in [this FAQ](http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.using.php#faq.using.shorthandbytes), may also be used.

I don’t know what makes them so confident that only *poorly written scripts* need to adjust this setting but I hope this brief introduction fulfils your need anyway.

Comment: Thanks. Increasing memory_limit or set it to -1 did not help to solve the problem,