# phpmyadmin import error of memory

Tags: import, phpmyadmin

I am facing below error message while I am trying to import a large file using phpmyadmin. What is the solution in this regard ?? Thanks

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 1134559232) (tried to allocate 32768 bytes) in X:\wamp\www\xxx](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23050090/fatal-error-out-of-memory-allocated-1134559232-tried-to-allocate-32768-bytes)

Comment: I know this is too late, but what is the file size limit shown in phpmyadimin? is it 2MB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try set upload_max_filesize, post_max_size , max_file_uploads and memory_limit to -1 in php.ini  and then restart your Apache server. If it did not work, try to set the mentioned parameters to -1 right on top of your codes.

Answer (score 0):

Check your php.ini file, you will find this code you can increase your size limit.
`post_max_size = 140M`

Comment: @abuabu post_max_size and memory_limit both needs to increase and restart apache